# Combination of sum and last element for a group with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by

I have following case where I'm struggling a bit.
We receive following kind of table (simplyfied), that we need to group by the concatinated PK.

| Composed_PKey | Vertriebsgrund_Key | Retoure_Soll_Haben_Kennzeichen | Auftragsmenge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1016626879-000010-ST | 33 | X | 20.0 |
| 1016626879-000010-ST | 33 | null | null |
| 1016626879-000010-ST | 33 | null | 20.0 |
| 1016626879-000010-ST | 33 | X | null |

The "tricky" issue is now that for the columns that have a amount inside (like "Auftragsmenge") it should be summed (Auftragsmenge=40) and for all the others it should always take that last value ("Retoure_Soll_Haben_Kennzeichen" = X).

I already thought of doing it in two steps (one table for the sum and the other for the last value) and then joining on PK, but I'm not sure if there isn't maybe an faster way.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you decide what is the "last value"? Is there an ordering column somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to answer your question:

```
(df
    .withColumn('Auftragsmenge', F.sum(F.col('Auftragsmenge')).over(W.partitionBy(F.col('Composed_PKey'))))
    .withColumn('Retoure_Soll_Haben_Kennzeichen', F.last(F.col('Retoure_Soll_Haben_Kennzeichen')).over(W.partitionBy(F.col('Composed_PKey'))))
    .withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy(F.col('Composed_PKey')).orderBy(F.col('Composed_PKey'))))
    .filter(F.col('rank') == 1)
    .drop('rank')
)
```

If you have a Date column on your dataset you also could replace the `.withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over` by a `F.rank()` function ordered by this Date column and you would achieve the same result.

The return of this code should be a table like this one:

| Composed_PKey | Vertriebsg... | Retoure_Soll_Haben_... | Auftragsm... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1016626879-000010-ST | 33 | X | 40 |

Comment: thanks, nice idea. As I have 10 more fields like 'Retoure_Soll_Haben_Kennzeichen' I would need to add some other "withColumn". So I need to check how fast that is then. But thanks!:)